# Retrieve 3 unique records within 1 while loop

Tags: php, sql, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

I know this might have a very simple solution but I just cannot seem to find it, I want to display 3 different records but at the moment I am getting the 1st record 3 times, then the 2nd and so on.

See image of results here:

[image]

I **specifically** want 3 different results, one spread across the 12 length bootstrap div and two spread across the two 6 length bootstrap divs.

```
$query="SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$counter = 0;
$max = 3;

while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) and ($counter < $max)) {

 echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
      echo '<h3><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h3>';
      echo '<small style="font-size: 12px;color:#ADACAD;"> Posted on '.date('l, jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</small>';
      echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';               
      echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a></p>';
    echo '</div>';
 echo '</div>';     

echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
      echo '<h3><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h3>';
      echo '<small style="font-size: 12px;color:#ADACAD;"> Posted on '.date('l, jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</small>';
      echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';               
      echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a></p>';
    echo '</div>';      
    echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
      echo '<h3><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h3>';
      echo '<small style="font-size: 12px;color:#ADACAD;"> Posted on '.date('l, jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</small>';
      echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';               
      echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a></p>';
    echo '</div>';      
echo '</div>';
$counter++; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you are doing 3 block div `echo` time for each loop

```
echo '<div class="row">';
.....   

echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
...      
echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
....
```

updated:

```
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) and ($counter < $max))
{
    if($counter == 0)
    {
        echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="col-md-12">';
        echo '<h3><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h3>';
        echo '<small style="font-size: 12px;color:#ADACAD;"> Posted on '.date('l, jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</small>';
        echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';
        echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a></p>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    elseif($counter == 1)
    {
        echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
        echo '<h3><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h3>';
        echo '<small style="font-size: 12px;color:#ADACAD;"> Posted on '.date('l, jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</small>';
        echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';
        echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a></p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
        echo '<h3><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h3>';
        echo '<small style="font-size: 12px;color:#ADACAD;"> Posted on '.date('l, jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</small>';
        echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';
        echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a></p>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: But I am specifically trying to input them into bootstrap divs of different lengths. The 1st row being 12 long and the 2nd row spilt by 6 each. Thats where the issue comes in.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks ewwink!

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this.

You need to work on your loops as well.

```
$query="SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$counter = 0;
$max = 3;
$divMd = 12;


while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) and ($counter < $max)) {

if($counter ==1){
   $divMd = 6;
 }

 if($counter!=2){
     echo '<div class="row">';
  }
    echo '<div class="col-md-'.$divMd.'">';
      echo '<h3><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h3>';
      echo '<small style="font-size: 12px;color:#ADACAD;"> Posted on '.date('l, jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</small>';
      echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';               
      echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a></p>';
    echo '</div>';

  if($counter!=1){
     echo '</div>'; 
   }    

$counter++; 

}
```

Comment: But I am specifically trying to input them into bootstrap divs of different lengths. The 1st row being 12 long and the 2nd row spilt by 6 each. Thats where the issue comes in.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the answer above by ewwink was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: That's great to know.